# How to make exception syntax from 2.** to 3.** work

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, except

```
def no():
    try:
        x = eval(input('Enter a number: '))
        y = eval(input("Enter a number: "))
        print(x/y)
    except (ZeroDivisionError, TypeError) , e:
        print('The second number cannot be zero!', e)
```

How do I make this work in 3.** python

Comment: You should always use `as e` instead of `, e`.  It works in Python2 as well as Python3, so using `as` makes it bothways-compatible.

Comment: @zondo: that doesn't work in Python 2.5 or older though.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.6 and up support the new `except .. as` syntax, just use that:

```
def no():
    try:
        x = eval(input('Enter a number: '))
        y = eval(input("Enter a number: "))
        print(x/y)
    except (ZeroDivisionError, TypeError) as e:
        print('The second number cannot be zero!', e)
```

See the [Python 2.6 *What's new* document](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3110-exception-handling-changes).

There is no need to use the old, deprecated `except .., e:` syntax in any code unless you need to support 2.5 or older, at which point your only option is to use [`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) in the handler to access the currently active exception:

```
def no():
    try:
        x = eval(input('Enter a number: '))
        y = eval(input("Enter a number: "))
        print(x/y)
    except (ZeroDivisionError, TypeError):
        # avoid using "as e" to support Python <= 2.5.
        e = sys.exc_info()[1]
        print('The second number cannot be zero!', e)
```